# I want to reuse an array that already has been modified

Tags: python, list

I am making a cinema booking system in Python and I am having trouble saving the modified array so it shows that the seat has been taken I am using this to create the array.

```
def seats():
    rows = "ABCDE"
    columns = range(0, 10)
    x = [{ltr + str(y): 'Empty' for ltr in rows} for y in columns]
    pprint(x)
    res = str(raw_input("Pick a seat "))
    if res[1] == '0':
        if x[0][res] == 'Taken':
            print ('Seat taken')
    else:
       x[0][res] = 'Taken'
```

Note that I'm not that experienced so any tips to make the code cleaner will be appraised as well. The customer should be able to buy multiple seats and I have that sorted out but if I return to the menu and then back to the seats, all the 'taken' seats appear as 'empty' again.

Comment: You are working with a *list*. I'm not sure exactly what the problem you are asking about is, but I suspect is has something to do with the fact that your function only has local variables, and doesn't return anything, so you can't see any of it's effects.

Comment: Initialise **x** outside of the **seats** function and pass it in as a parameter

Comment: Also, it seems to me you are only ever working with the first row, no?

Comment: I already have the code for the rest of the rows, but I did not want copy and paste it all. I´ll give your suggestions a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you would want to put it in a class and define `x` as an attribute. I have changed quite a lot, not quite sure whether this is what you want. For example I have renamed `x` to `self.seats` and changed it's structure to be a `dict` only instead of a `list` of `dict`s because that seems easier to me.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
class Cinema(object):

     def __init__(self, rows, columns):
         self.rows = rows
         self.columns = columns
         # True: seat is free, seat is availbale
         self.seats = {"{row}{col}".format(row=row, col=col): True for row in rows for col in columns}

     def ask_for_seat(self):
         print("The following seats are still available:")
         self.print_free_seats()
         seat = input("Pick a seat: ")
         if seat in self.seats:
             if self.seats[seat]:
                 print("Thank you. We are reserving seat {} for you.".format(seat))
                 self.seats[seat] = False
                 return seat
             else:
                 print("Seat {} is already reserved. Please choose another one.".format(seat))
                 return self.ask_for_seat()
         else:
             print("Sorry, this cinema does not have a seat {}. Please choose another one.".format(seat))
             return self.ask_for_seat()

     def print_free_seats(self):
         for row in self.rows:
             for col in self.columns:
                 seat = "{row}{col}".format(row=row, col=col)
                 if self.seats[seat]:
                     print(seat, end=" ")
                 else:
                     print(" "*len(seat), end=" ")
             print()


if __name__=='__main__':
     c = Cinema("ABCDE", range(0, 10))
     while True:
         c.ask_for_seat()
```

Please note that this is Python 3 code and does not work with Python 2.